# Understanding proof of LUB property (Buck)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Here is the proof given by Buck, abridged. My question is listed below.

Theorem 17 If $S$ is any bounded nonempty set of real numbers, sup $(S)$ and inf $(S)$ exist.

Let $\mathscr{L}$ be the set of lower bounds for S.

Choose $a_{0}$ as the largest integer in $\mathscr{L}$. Clearly, $a_{0} \geq 0$. Then, choose $a_{1}$ as the largest integer $n$ such that $n / 2 \in \mathscr{L}$. Noting that $a_{0}=\left(2 a_{0}\right) / 2,$ we see that $2 a_{0}$ is one of these possible values of $n,$ so that $2 a_{0} \leq a_{1} .$ In general,we choose $a_{k}$ as the largest integer $n$ such that $n / 2^{k} \in \mathscr{L} .$ We therefore have $a_{k} / 2^{k}$ in $\mathscr{L},$ for $k=0,1,2, \ldots$ We move on to $a_{k+1},$ which is to be the largest integer $n$ such that $n / 2^{k+1}$ is in $\mathscr{L},$ and note that $\left(2 a_{k}\right) / 2^{k+1}=a_{k} / 2^{k}$ thus we see that $2 a_{k}$ is a possible value of $n$ and $2 a_{k} \leq a_{k+1}$. Accordingly, we have constructed a sequence $\left\{a_{n} / 2^{n}\right\}$ whose terms are rational numbers and are all in the set $\mathscr{L},$ and such that
$$
a_{0} \leq \frac{a_{1}}{2} \leq \frac{a_{2}}{4} \leq \frac{a_{3}}{8} \leq \cdots \leq \frac{a_{n}}{2^{n}} \leq \cdots \leq s
$$
As a bounded monotonic sequence, this converges, and we set $L=$ $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} / 2^{n}$. If $x$ is any member of $S,$ then since $a_{n} / 2^{n}$ belongs to $\mathscr{L}$ $a_{n} / 2^{n} \leq x$ for every $n$ and $L \leq x ;$ but since this holds for every $x \in S, L$ is a lower bound for $S$ and $L \in \mathscr{L}$. The only remaining task is to show that $L$ is the largest member of $\mathscr{L}$. Suppose that there were a number $b \in \mathscr{L}$ with $L<b .$ Since, for any $k, a_{k} / 2^{k} \leq L<b,$ we have $a_{k} \leq 2^{k} L<2^{k} b .$ If we take $k$ sufficiently large, there will be an integer $N$ between $2^{k} L$ and $2^{k} b,$ with $a_{k}<N$. Accordingly, the integer $a_{k}$ could not have been the largest integer $n$ such that $n / 2^{k} \in \mathscr{L},$ since $N$ would have the same property. Thus, there cannot exist a number $b \in \mathscr{L}$ with $b>L,$ and $L$ is the largest member of $\mathscr{L}$.

> My question is, why did Buck need to construct the sequence ${\frac{a_n}{2^n}}$, when this is equivalent to choosing $b$ as the largest element that exists in $\mathscr{L}$ such that $\frac{a_n}{2^n} = b_n \in \mathscr{L}$? Why can't one just construct a monotonically increasing sequence by choosing $b \in \mathscr{L}$ as the largest element, then define the sequence recursively:
> $$
> b_0 \leq b_1 \leq b_2 \leq \cdots
> $$
> In other words, why the $2^n$?

Source:

> Buck, Advanced Calculus, Chapter 1, Theorem 17

Comment: I don't understand how you're proposing to define the recursive sequence $b_0 \le b_1 \le b_2 \le ...$  Remember that $\mathscr{L}$ may not have a largest element (if it did, then the largest element must be the sup and we don't have to do anything else).

Comment: @Ted I mean construct the sequence $(b_n)$ just like how the author constructed the sequence $(a_n/2^n)$. I did contradict myself a little, but what I meant was choose $b$ **as** the largest element.

Comment: I still don't understand. When you say "construct a monotonically increasing sequence by choosing $b \in \mathscr{L}$ as the largest element": the largest element of *what* ?

Comment: @Ted I think what Buck wanted to say was that choose a random element of $\mathscr{L}$, say $a_0$ then call it the largest element **of** $\mathscr{L}$. We don't know whether it is indeed the largest. So, let $a_1$ be another element, also chosen as the 'largest' element of $\mathscr{L}$, so $a_0 \leq a_1$. Then repeat, so we have the a monotonically increasing sequence.

Comment: You are going to have to make very clear what are the assumed axioms, because **usually** the completeness property (LUB) is used to *prove* MCT (the monotone convergence theorem) for sequences, so where did you get MCT from?

Comment: @user21820 The book takes MCT as an axiom, at least to the extent where this post is concerned.

Comment: Ok. Then I agree with Ted that your use of the word "largest" makes absolutely no sense at all. You do **not** say "largest" unless it **really** is the largest.

Comment: Buck does not say to choose $a_0$ as the largest element of $\mathscr{L}$.  Buck says to choose $a_0$ as the largest _integer_ in $\mathscr{L}$.  That makes sense because $\mathscr{L}$ is bounded, and a bounded set of integers always has a largest element. It doesn't make sense to put 'largest' in quotes like that, when it really isn't the largest: what would that mean?